# How to make copy-paste friendly typedef for OuterClass in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, code-generation, rtti, visual-c++-2010

I noticed that the manual designation typedef on OuterClass too costly and sometimes leads to embarrassing errors.
So I decided to make a copy-paste friendly typedef on OuterClass.
Here's what I got:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A{
  typedef A NextOuterClass;
  typedef A SelfClass;
  struct B{
    typedef NextOuterClass OuterClass;
    typedef B NextOuterClass;
    typedef B SelfClass;
    struct C{
      typedef NextOuterClass OuterClass;
      typedef C NextOuterClass;
      typedef C SelfClass;
    };
  };
};

#define CHECK(OWNER,TYPE)\
  static_assert(\
  std::is_same<OWNER::TYPE::OuterClass,OWNER>::value,\
  #OWNER"::"#TYPE" - not ok"\
);
CHECK(A,B);
CHECK(A::B,C);
#undef CHECK

int main(){return 0;}
```

It works quite well, but not always:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct I{
  typedef I NextOuterClass;
  typedef I SelfClass;
};

struct D{
  typedef D NextOuterClass;
  typedef D SelfClass;
  struct E:public I{
    typedef NextOuterClass OuterClass; // NextOuterClass == I::NextOuterClass
    typedef E NextOuterClass;
    typedef E SelfClass;
    typedef I ParentClass;
  };
};

#define CHECK(OWNER,TYPE)\
  static_assert(\
  std::is_same<OWNER::TYPE::OuterClass,OWNER>::value,\
  #OWNER"::"#TYPE" - not ok"\
);
CHECK(D,E); // D::E - not ok
#undef CHECK

int main(){return 0;}
```

If I remove the "typedef I NextOuterClass;", then it will work, but it is a bad decision because the class "I" may also have sub-classes:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct I{
  typedef I NextOuterClass;
  typedef I SelfClass;
  struct G{
    typedef NextOuterClass OuterClass;
    typedef G NextOuterClass;
    typedef G SelfClass;
  };
};

struct D{
  typedef D NextOuterClass;
  typedef D SelfClass;
  struct E:public I{
    typedef NextOuterClass OuterClass; // NextOuterClass == I::NextOuterClass
    typedef E NextOuterClass;
    typedef E SelfClass;
    typedef I ParentClass;
  };
};

#define CHECK(OWNER,TYPE)\
  static_assert(\
  std::is_same<OWNER::TYPE::OuterClass,OWNER>::value,\
  #OWNER"::"#TYPE" - not ok"\
);
CHECK(I,G);
CHECK(D,E); // D::E - not ok
#undef CHECK

int main(){return 0;}
```

I have tried to exploit the features of "private" and "template", but still has not reached the desired behavior.

In C++11 or C++14 have any reliable way to find OuterClass?

It would be nice to have such things here:

```
std::get_outer_class<T>::type
std::is_nested_class<T>::value
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is ill-formed:

> **3.3.7/1** The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> 1. The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following
>      the name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, brace-or-equal-initializers of non-static
>      data members, and default arguments in that class (including such things in nested classes).
> 2. A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in
>      the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.
> 3. If reordering member declarations in a class yields an alternate valid program under (1) and (2), the
>      program is ill-formed, no diagnostic is required.

Your approach relies on the name `NextOuterClass` referring to different things at different points in the nested class definition. Which is precisely what (2) prohibits.

Comment: I realize this is more of a comment than an answer, but the explanation required too much text to fit into a comment.